# (Python) Using a for loop to pack Buttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and Tkinter and wanted to make a Calendar. I wanted to start by having 12 Buttons that all have a month from January to December on them, using a for loop. When I run the code all I get is a window that has a blank, small Button on it. What am I doing wrong?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
days = []
for number in range(1, 32):
    days.append(number)



def monthpacking(list1):
    month = ""
    month_button = Button(master,
                          text=month)
    for item in list1:
        month = item
        month_button.pack()

monthpacking(months)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're only creating a single button. If you want to create 12 buttons, you'll need to create the button inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the code for you based on Bryan Oakley's comment

```
def monthpacking(list1):
    for item in list1:
        month = item
        month_button = Button(master,
                          text=month)
        month_button.pack()
```